# Terminology for style where melody uses low notes?

Tags: terminology, arranging

Usually the notes that compose the melody are the high notes, and accompaniment are low notes. However, for some arrangements, I've noticed one style flips this by putting the melody in the low notes and adds accompanying high notes, like in [this arrangement for the Tetris theme](https://musescore.com/user/15503/scores/74003).

[image: Tetris Theme arr. roticanai, mm. 1–4]

What is the formal name for this style of arrangement?

Answer (score 3):

There's no special term for this. The typical description would be something along the lines of "an arrangement with the melody in the bass" or "the melody in the lowest voice".